# Retirar tag do WP com PHP

Tags: php

Colegas.

Estamos criando um novo sistema e retirando o WP, porém as notícias ainda pegaremos do WP, como notícias antigas. Só que quando trazemos a coluna post_content, ele me traz a tag que aparece ao lado da imagem:

> [caption id="attachment_9472" align="alignleft" width="350"](aqui
>   aparece a imagem)[/caption]

Tentei usar o strip_tags, mas não funcionou. Estamos pegando sem usar o WP e sim nosso próprio sistema. Como faço para retirar essas tags e deixar somente a imagem?

Estou pegando dessa forma:

```
<?php echo utf8_encode(strip_tags($jmVisualizar->post_content),'[caption]'); ?>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usando RegEx, essa é uma das maneiras mais simples:

```
preg_replace('/\[\/?caption.*\]/U', '', $string )
```

Basicamente ela troca tudo que está dentro de `[ ]` e começa com `caption` ou `/caption`. O modificador `/U` serve para pegar o menor pedaço possível, para que o papa-tudo `.*` não pegue coisas entre duas tags diferentes.

Se quiser **remover todas as tags com `[ ]`** a situação pode até simplificar:

```
preg_replace('/\[.*\]/U', '', $string );
                           ^--- aqui você põe um espaço se não for para "colar" tudo.
```

Se precisar fazer algo de diferente com as partes antes e depois do `caption`:

```
preg_replace( '/(.*)\[caption.*\](.*)\[\/caption\](.*)/', '$1$2$3', $string );
```

Se não precisar da parte de fora da tag, **e quiser só o conteúdo**:

```
preg_replace( '/.*\[caption.*\](.*)\[\/caption\].*/', '$1', $string );
```

Se quiser **remover a tag e o conteúdo**:

```
preg_replace( '/.*\[caption.*\].*\[\/caption\].*/', '', $string );
```

Veja todos testes funcionando no **[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/7Kt5ic)**.

Tem outras mil maneiras de resolver, tudo depende de pequenos detalhes das variações que seus dados podem ter.

Comment: Perfeito Bacco, funcionou! Muito obrigado.

Comment: @Fox.11  Eu geralmente evito usar RegEx à toa, mas neste seu caso específico, é uma ferramenta bem adequada para fazer o serviço. Deixei alguns exemplos no IDEONE, para você ver qual presta mais para o seu caso, mas qualquer dúvida, avise.

Comment: Combinado......